# Pass appendTo value to the $uibModal.open() function

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Can I pass the value for the `appendTo` parameter to the angular bootstrap function `$uibModal.open()` ?

Something like this:

```
var options;
options.appendElement = $document.find('aside-box').eq(0);
return $uibModal.open(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the attribute resolve

```
$uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modaltemplate.tpl.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'modalCtrl',
        resolve: {
          myparameter: function() {
            return 'teste param';
          }
        });

var ModalCtrl = function(myparameter, $modalInstance) {
  console.log(myparameter);
}

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('ModalCtrl', ModalCtrl)
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I mean the option from the API. I already font some topic (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5404)